# How to put an image, paragraph and then another image all in the same line?

Tags: html, css

I'm want to put an image, a paragraph and then another image in one line in html/css.

I got it to work this way.

```
<html>
<body>
        <span style="float:left; display: inline-block; width: 20%;">
        <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/762369348300251136/5Obhonwa.jpg"  
         width="90" height="110" />
        </span>
        <span style="float:left;width: 60%;">
            <p style="float:left; display:block;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,    
                consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer arcu mauris, ullamcorper et 
                ligula vitae, hendrerit sodales tellus. Maecenas quis pulvinar 
                lacus.</p>
        </span>
        <span style="float:right; width 20%;">
            <img src="https://www.google.ca/doodle4google/images/splashes/featured.png" width="90" height="110">
        </span>  
</body>
</html>
```

I know i could do it in an external css sheet or style tags but it's for an assignment so i have to do all three.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example : https://jsfiddle.net/sp6ykv66/

HTML:

```
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
<p class="inline">Lorem Ipsum</p>
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" alt="">
```

CSS:

```
.inline{display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
flex-direction:row;
}

.children{
// whatever you want
// your paragraph and imgs need to be children of parent
}
```

so you paragraph and imgs needs to be in a div class="parent"

so display:flex affects divs children aka paragraph and imgs

Note: Im on phone

Answer (score 0):

You can either use (on the h4 elements, as they are block by default)

```
display: inline-block;
```

Or you can float the elements to the left/rght

```
float: left;
```

Just don't forget to clear the floats after

```
clear: left;
```

**or try it**

```css
h4{width:80px;float:left}
```

```html
<h4 class='liketext'><img style='height: 24px; width: 24px; margin-right: 4px;' src='design/like.png'/>$likes</h4>
<h4 class='liketext'> <img style='height: 24px; width: 24px; margin-right: 4px;' src='design/dislike.png'/></h4>
```